# How to check if an element is in an array

Tags: arrays, swift

In Swift, how can I check if an element exists in an array? Xcode does not have any suggestions for `contain`, `include`, or `has`, and a quick search through the book turned up nothing. Any idea how to check for this? I know that there is a method `find` that returns the index number, but is there a method that returns a boolean like ruby's `#include?`?

Example of what I need:

```
var elements = [1,2,3,4,5]
if elements.contains(5) {
  //do something
}
```

Comment: `if find(elements, 5) != nil {  }` is not good enough?

Comment: I was hoping for something even cleaner, but its not looking good. I haven't found anything in the documentation or the book yet.

Answer (score 996, accepted):

**Swift 2, 3, 4, 5:**

```
let elements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
if elements.contains(5) {
    print("yes")
}
```

`contains()` is a *protocol extension method* of [`SequenceType`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence) (for sequences of `Equatable` elements) and not a global method as in
earlier releases.

*Remarks:*

- This `contains()` method requires that the sequence elements
  adopt the `Equatable` protocol, compare e.g. [Andrews's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33532399/1187415).
- If the sequence elements are instances of a `NSObject` subclass
  then you have to override `isEqual:`, see [NSObject subclass in Swift: hash vs hashValue, isEqual vs ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319959/nsobject-subclass-in-swift-hash-vs-hashvalue-isequal-vs).
- There is another – more general – `contains()` method which does not require the elements to be equatable and takes a predicate as an 
  argument, see e.g. [Shorthand to test if an object exists in an array for Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29679486/shorthand-to-test-if-an-object-exists-in-an-array-for-swift).

**Swift older versions:**

```
let elements = [1,2,3,4,5]
if contains(elements, 5) {
    println("yes")
}
```

Comment: Any documentation about this kind of global functions?

Comment: Is this supposed to work if each item inside the array (and the item we are searching for) is of type Dictionary<String, AnyObject>? Trying to achieve that but I get compile-time error.

Comment: @ppalancica: This requires that the array elements conform to the `Equatable` protocol (which `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>` doesn't). There is a second variant of `contains()` which takes a predicate (compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29679486/shorthand-to-test-if-an-object-exists-in-an-array-for-swift) perhaps you can use that, e.g. `if contains(array, { $0 == dict } ) ...`

Comment: How to search specific element from generic array? say [AnyObject] ?

Answer (score 155):

For those who came here looking for a find and remove an object from an array:

**Swift 1**

```
if let index = find(itemList, item) {
    itemList.removeAtIndex(index)
}
```

**Swift 2**

```
if let index = itemList.indexOf(item) {
    itemList.removeAtIndex(index)
}
```

**Swift 3, 4**

```
if let index = itemList.index(of: item) {
    itemList.remove(at: index)
}
```

**Swift 5.2**

```
if let index = itemList.firstIndex(of: item) {
    itemList.remove(at: index)
}
```

Answer (score 70):

**Updated for Swift 2+**

Note that as of Swift 3 (or even 2), the extension below is no longer necessary as the global `contains` function has been made into a pair of extension method on `Array`, which allow you to do either of:

```
let a = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]

a.contains(2)           // => true, only usable if Element : Equatable

a.contains { $0 < 1 }   // => false
```

**Historical Answer for Swift 1:**

Use this extension: (updated to **Swift 5.2**)

```
 extension Array {
     func contains<T>(obj: T) -> Bool where T: Equatable {
         return !self.filter({$0 as? T == obj}).isEmpty
     }
 }
```

Use as:

```
array.contains(1)
```

Comment: depending on what you're used to though, .contains may feel more intuitive and memorable

Comment: Could you explain your syntax by breaking it down? I've never seen this formatting before and you've got a lot of advanced stuff happening at once!

Comment: I changed the original code to use .isEmpty as it is a practice suggested by SwiftLint.

Comment: Don't use this extension, it's horrible. Just use https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2945493-contains

Comment: Great when people with no concept of the history of the language make judgements like this.  Note the section on "Updated for Swift 2/3" that's when `contains` was added to the language.

Answer (score 47):

If you are checking if an instance of a **custom class or struct** is contained in an array, you'll need to implement the **Equatable** protocol before you can use .contains(myObject).

For example:

```
struct Cup: Equatable {
    let filled:Bool
}

static func ==(lhs:Cup, rhs:Cup) -> Bool { // Implement Equatable
    return lhs.filled == rhs.filled
}
```

then you can do:

```
cupArray.contains(myCup)
```

**Tip**: The == override should be at the global level, not within your class/struct

Comment: Attention: This does not check whether an instance of a custom class or struct is in the array. It checks whether there is an element that evaluates its == operator as true given the param to contains() to compare with. Example: An array of pointer wrapper objects that implement == to return whether both objects point to the same memory address would completely break this solution.

Answer (score 32):

I used filter.

```
let results = elements.filter { el in el == 5 }
if results.count > 0 {
    // any matching items are in results
} else {
    // not found
}
```

If you want, you can compress that to

```
if elements.filter({ el in el == 5 }).count > 0 {
}
```

Hope that helps.

---

**Update for Swift 2**

Hurray for default implementations!

```
if elements.contains(5) {
    // any matching items are in results
} else {
    // not found
}
```

Comment: I like the filter solution because you can use it for all sorts of things. For instance, I was porting some code that looped and looped trying to see if a list already had an item with one of it's fields containing a string value. It's *one line* in Swift, using a filter on that field.

Comment: filter is inefficient because it always loops over all elements instead of returning immediately when the element is found. Better use find() instead.

Answer (score 26):

*(Swift 3)*

#### Check if an element exists in an array (fulfilling some criteria), *and if so, proceed working with the first such element*

If the intent is:

1. To check whether an element exist in an array (/fulfils some boolean criteria, not necessarily equality testing),
2. And if so, proceed and work with the first such element,

Then an alternative to [`contains(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence/1641180-contains) as blueprinted `Sequence` is to [`first(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence/1849238-first) of `Sequence`:

```
let elements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

if let firstSuchElement = elements.first(where: { $0 == 4 }) {
    print(firstSuchElement) // 4
    // ...
}
```

In this contrived example, its usage might seem silly, but it's very useful if querying arrays of non-fundamental element types for existence of any elements fulfilling some condition. E.g.

```
struct Person {
    let age: Int
    let name: String
    init(_ age: Int, _ name: String) {
        self.age = age
        self.name = name
    }
}

let persons = [Person(17, "Fred"),   Person(16, "Susan"),
               Person(19, "Hannah"), Person(18, "Sarah"),
               Person(23, "Sam"),    Person(18, "Jane")]

if let eligableDriver = persons.first(where: { $0.age >= 18 }) {
    print("\(eligableDriver.name) can possibly drive the rental car in Sweden.")
    // ...
} // Hannah can possibly drive the rental car in Sweden.

let daniel = Person(18, "Daniel")
if let sameAgeAsDaniel = persons.first(where: { $0.age == daniel.age }) {
    print("\(sameAgeAsDaniel.name) is the same age as \(daniel.name).")
    // ...
} // Sarah is the same age as Daniel.
```

Any chained operations using `.filter { ... some condition }.first` can favourably be replaced with `first(where:)`. The latter shows intent better, and have performance advantages over possible non-lazy appliances of `.filter`, as these will pass the full array prior to extracting the (possible) first element passing the filter.

---

#### Check if an element exists in an array (fulfilling some criteria), *and if so, remove the first such element*

A comment below queries:

> How can I remove the `firstSuchElement` from the array?

A similar use case to the one above is to *remove* the first element that fulfils a given predicate. To do so, the [`index(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection/1641205-index) method of [`Collection`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/CollectionAlgorithms.swift.gyb#L104) (which is readily available to array collection) may be used to find the index of the first element fulfilling the predicate, whereafter the index can be used with the [`remove(at:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1641390-remove) method of `Array` to (possible; given that it exists) remove that element.

```
var elements = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c"]

if let indexOfFirstSuchElement = elements.index(where: { $0 == "c" }) {
    elements.remove(at: indexOfFirstSuchElement)
    print(elements) // ["a", "b", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c"]
}
```

Or, if you'd like to remove the element from the array *and work with*, apply `Optional`:s [`map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/optional/1539476-map) method to conditionally (for `.some(...)` return from `index(where:)`) use the result from `index(where:)` to remove and capture the removed element from the array (within an optional binding clause).

```
var elements = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c"]

if let firstSuchElement = elements.index(where: { $0 == "c" })
    .map({ elements.remove(at: $0) }) {

    // if we enter here, the first such element have now been
    // remove from the array
    print(elements) // ["a", "b", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c"]

    // and we may work with it
    print(firstSuchElement) // c
}
```

Note that in the contrived example above the array members are simple value types (`String` instances), so using a predicate to find a given member is somewhat over-kill, as we might simply test for equality using the simpler `index(of:)` method as shown in [@DogCoffee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29876138/4573247). If applying the find-and-remove approach above to the `Person` example, however, using `index(where:)` with a predicate is appropriate (since we no longer test for equality but for fulfilling a supplied predicate).

Comment: How can I remove the firstSuchElement from the array?

Comment: @i6x86 thanks for the question. I updated my answer with an example of how to remove the element (and also how to remove and capture the removed element).

Answer (score 22):

An array that contains a property that equals to

```
yourArray.contains(where: {$0.propertyToCheck == value })
```

Returns boolean.

Answer (score 14):

The simplest way to accomplish this is to use filter on the array.

```
let result = elements.filter { $0==5 }
```

`result` will have the found element if it exists and will be empty if the element does not exist. So simply checking if `result` is empty will tell you whether the element exists in the array. I would use the following:

```
if result.isEmpty {
    // element does not exist in array
} else {
    // element exists
}
```

Comment: great solution. so this method returns an array. However, I'm using this to look for an "id". In my application d's are unique, so there can be only one result. Is there a way to return just 1 result? I'm using result[0] for now

Comment: @DanBeaulieu Doing something like `let result = elements.filter { $0==5 }.first` should accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: @davetw12 No. This would unnecessarily iterate the whole collection. Better to use `first(where: predicate)`.

Answer (score 10):

**Swift 4/5**

Another way to achieve this is with the filter function

```
var elements = [1,2,3,4,5]
if let object = elements.filter({ $0 == 5 }).first {
    print("found")
} else {
    print("not found")
}
```

Comment: This would unnecessarily iterate the whole collection. This is definitely the wrong approach.

Answer (score 7):

#### Array

```
let elements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]
```

#### Check elements presence

```
elements.contains(5) // true
```

#### Get elements index

```
elements.firstIndex(of: 5) // 4
elements.firstIndex(of: 10) // nil
```

#### Get element count

```
let results = elements.filter { element in element == 5 }
results.count // 2
```

Answer (score 6):

As of Swift 2.1 NSArrays have `containsObject`that can be used like so:

```
if myArray.containsObject(objectImCheckingFor){
    //myArray has the objectImCheckingFor
}
```

Comment: Actually that is for an NSArray. Not a swift array

Comment: Yeah, but you can temporary convert your swift array to NSArray: if let tempNSArrayForChecking = mySwiftArray as NSArray? where tempNSArrayForChecking.containsObject(objectImCheckingFor) {//myArray has the object }

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anybody is trying to find if an `indexPath` is among the selected ones (like in a `UICollectionView` or `UITableView` `cellForItemAtIndexPath` functions):

```
    var isSelectedItem = false
    if let selectedIndexPaths = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems() as? [NSIndexPath]{
        if contains(selectedIndexPaths, indexPath) {
            isSelectedItem = true
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my little extension I just wrote to check if my delegate array contains a delegate object or not (**Swift 2**). :) It Also works with value types like a charm.

```
extension Array
{
    func containsObject(object: Any) -> Bool
    {
        if let anObject: AnyObject = object as? AnyObject
        {
            for obj in self
            {
                if let anObj: AnyObject = obj as? AnyObject
                {
                    if anObj === anObject { return true }
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

If you have an idea how to optimize this code, than just let me know.

Answer (score 2):

if user find particular array elements  then use below  code same as integer value.

```
var arrelemnts = ["sachin", "test", "test1", "test3"]

 if arrelemnts.contains("test"){
    print("found")   }else{
    print("not found")   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add an extension for `Array` as such:

```
extension Array {
     func contains<T>(_ object: T) -> Bool where T: Equatable {
         !self.filter {$0 as? T == object }.isEmpty
     }
 }
```

This can be used as:

```
if myArray.contains(myItem) {
   // code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift

If you are not using object then you can user this code for contains.

```
let elements = [ 10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

if elements.contains(50) {

   print("true")

}
```

If you are using NSObject Class in swift. This variables is according to my requirement. you can modify for your requirement.

```
var cliectScreenList = [ATModelLeadInfo]()
var cliectScreenSelectedObject: ATModelLeadInfo!
```

This is for a same data type.

```
{ $0.user_id == cliectScreenSelectedObject.user_id }
```

If you want to AnyObject type.

```
{ "\($0.user_id)" == "\(cliectScreenSelectedObject.user_id)" }
```

Full condition

```
if cliectScreenSelected.contains( { $0.user_id == cliectScreenSelectedObject.user_id } ) == false {

    cliectScreenSelected.append(cliectScreenSelectedObject)

    print("Object Added")

} else {

    print("Object already exists")

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

what about using a hash table for the job, like this?

first, creating a "hash map" generic function, extending the Sequence protocol.

```
extension Sequence where Element: Hashable {

    func hashMap() -> [Element: Int] {
        var dict: [Element: Int] = [:]
        for (i, value) in self.enumerated() {
            dict[value] = i
        }
        return dict
    }
}
```

This extension will work as long as the items in the array conform to Hashable, like integers or strings, here is the usage...

```
let numbers = Array(0...50) 
let hashMappedNumbers = numbers.hashMap()

let numToDetect = 35

let indexOfnumToDetect = hashMappedNumbers[numToDetect] // returns the index of the item and if all the elements in the array are different, it will work to get the index of the object!

print(indexOfnumToDetect) // prints 35
```

But for now, let's just focus in check if the element is in the array.

```
let numExists = indexOfnumToDetect != nil // if the key does not exist 
means the number is not contained in the collection.

print(numExists) // prints true
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.2 +**
You can easily verify your instance is an array or not by the following function.

```swift
func verifyIsObjectOfAnArray<T>(_ object: T) -> Bool {
   if let _ = object as? [T] {
      return true
   }

   return false
}
```

Even you can access it as follows. You will receive `nil` if the object wouldn't be an array.

```swift
func verifyIsObjectOfAnArray<T>(_ object: T) -> [T]? {
   if let array = object as? [T] {
      return array
   }

   return nil
}
```