# swift check if two array contains Same element and get the element?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

How can I compare two arrays in swift which have a common element and get that element?

```
let a1 = [1, 2, 3]
let a2 = [4, 2, 5]
```

I want to compare a1 and a2 and get result `2` from comparison in swift 2.2. How?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25714985/how-to-determine-if-one-array-contains-all-elements-of-another-array-in-swift

Comment: Check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439289/how-to-get-list-of-common-elements-of-2-array-in-swift?rq=1

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use **filter** function of swift

```
let a1 = [1, 2, 3]
let a2 = [4, 2, 5]

let a = a1.filter () { a2.contains($0) }

print(a)
```

print :  [2]

if data is

```
let a1 = [1, 2, 3]
let a2 = [4, 2, 3, 5]
```

print :  [2, 3]

If you want result in Int not in array

```
let result = a.first
```

You get optional Int(Int?) with result of first common element

Comment: Yes, It is work for all array.
condition is only both array are same type.

Here is [Int] array

Comment: How can i get a not in array but simple Int?

Comment: @JasonBourne Is your arrays have only one common object?

Comment: Lets say it has one common object

Comment: Here always possibility of getting more then one elements same in both array. So it will always return array.

Comment: But if you want only first element or must one same element then use

let first = a.first

Comment: You should use a `Set` to speed up the `.contains()` call.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative would to use Sets:

```
let a1 = [1, 2, 3]
let a2 = [4, 2, 5]

let a = Set(a1).intersection(Set(a2)) // <- getting the element itself
print(a) // 2

let contains: Bool = !Set(a1).isDisjoint(with: Set(a2)) // <- checking if they have any common element
print(contains) // true
```