# How to check if element of an array is in another array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, filter

I have two `Array` holding the instances of class `MYItems`. `FavoriteItems` holds the favorite items from the array `Items`

```
var Items :[MYItems] = []
var favoriteItems = [MYItems]()
```

Now i want to check if the Items array contains the favoriteItems  in the . How can i acheive this? i tried using the below Find method

```
if let index = find(favoriteItems, Items[indexPath.row]){

             println("found item")
   }else{
             println("doesnotcontains item")
        }
```

I tried using the below but that doesnot help too..

```
 if contains(favoriteItems, Items[indexPath.row]){

            println("found item")

        }else{

         println("doesnot contain item")

        }
```

But it always goes to the else block? Why is this happening when i contain one of the items in array for sure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if an element is in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102024/how-to-check-if-an-element-is-in-an-array)

Comment: Althoug duplicate is about element in an array, the answer still applies and questions are similar

Comment: although same...but that doesnot solve for me..so i am asking if there is some another thing to know

Comment: Could you explain why it does not “help you”. Do you require a index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you are searching for the problem in the wrong place.
You code on how to search through the array is indeed correct.

```
var Items :[Int] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,]
var favoriteItems:[Int] = [1,3,4,5,7]

if contains(Items, favoriteItems[3]){
  println("found item")
}else{
  println("doesnotcontains item")
}
```

Does work in swift 1.2.
The fourth item of `favoriteItems` (5) is indeed inside `Items` and it also does print `found item`

For your use with custom classes, you should make your class `Equatable` to do so you much make the class conform to the `Equatable` protocol.

```
func == (lhs:MyItem, rhs:MyItem) -> Bool{
  return lhs.id == rhs.id
}

class MyItem :Equatable {
  let id:Int
  init(id:Int){
    self.id = id
  }
}

var Items :[MyItem] = [MyItem(id: 1), MyItem(id:2), MyItem(id:4), MyItem(id:5)]
var favoriteItems:[MyItem] = [MyItem(id: 1), MyItem(id:2)]

if contains(Items, favoriteItems[1]){
  println("found item")
}else{
  println("doesnotcontains item")
}
```

Comment: what is this func == (lhs:MyItem, rhs:MyItem) -> Bool{
  return lhs.id == rhs.id
}..it gives me error

Comment: it makes the class conform to the equatable protocol

Answer (score 2):

Convert the arrays to a Set and then use `isSubsetOf`:

```
let itemsSet = Set(Items)
let favoritesSet = Set(favoriteItems)
let result = favoritesSet.isSubsetOf(itemsSet)
```

Comment: its crashing on last line

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableSet *intersection = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:aArray];
[intersection intersectSet:[NSSet setWithArray:bArray]];
NSArray *intrsecArray = [intersection allObjects];
```

Subset of objects in bArray that are not present in aArray:

```
NSMutableArray *cArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:bArray];
[cArray removeObjectsInArray:aArray];
```

Comment: This answer would be better if it were to use the same language as the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, use the following method of NSArray

```
id commonObject = [array1 firstObjectCommonWithArray:array2];
```

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsarray/1408825-firstobjectcommonwitharray?language=objc