# Check if an array already contains a string value in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, nsarray

I have an `Array` that is declared as:

```
var stringsArray: Array<String!> = []
```

I want to add items to it using code along these lines:

```
stringsArray.append("String 1")
```

However, I would like to use an `if` statement to detect whether or not what is about to be appended already exists in `stringsArray` and if it does, I would like the code to append not to be ran.

I am using Swift.

Comment: Maybe a `Set` would be a better choice?...

Comment: @Alladinian: I would turn your comment into an answer - that **is the solution**

Comment: A `Set` does not have defined ordering but I do need to be manipulate the order of the contents. Am I able to do this using a `Set`?

Comment: @DanielBramhall Then I guess you could use an `NSMutableOrderedSet`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use this:

```
var elements = [1,2,3,4,5]
if contains(elements, 5) {
    print("Array contains 3")
}
```

For Swift 2.2 and later, there is a *member* `contains()`:

```
var elements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
if elements.contains(3) {
    print("Array contains 3")
}
```

Resource: [How to check if an element is in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102024/how-to-check-if-an-element-is-in-an-array/25391725#25391725).

Comment: If you copy code verbatim from another answer then you should add a link to the source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25391725/1187415.

Comment: This doesn't work as it says that Swift cannot find an overload for `contains` that accepts an argument list of type `(Array<String!>, String)`

Comment: True that, forgot about that, editing in a minute.

Comment: Any ideas regarding my issue? Thanks!

Comment: Check the link above, that should solve your problem.