# How to check value exists in array of dictionary as value?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

```
{
        QueueId = 27;
        SongId = 38;
        artWorkURL = "<null>";
        duration = 58258;
        "stream_url" = "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/233301835/stream";
        title = Magenta;
        trackID = 233301835;
        userAvatar = "https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000188204071-llusgk-large.jpg";
        userName = Agiv;
    },
            {
        QueueId = 27;
        SongId = 39;
        artWorkURL = "<null>";
        duration = 79000;
        "stream_url" = "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/233301833/stream";
        title = Nino;
        trackID = 233301833;
        userAvatar = "https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000157591669-eva3mg-large.jpg";
        userName = "SWR Umwelt und Ern\U00e4hrung";
    }
```

My array of dictionary format is as above and multiple tracks i want to check `27` is already there or not ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31315232/check-if-value-is-in-the-array-as-dictionary-value already checked this not working

Comment: You can iterate over whole array and parse each dictionary individually to check for `trackID` 25.

Comment: is this an array or dictionary?. As far as i know you cannot add key-value pairs to an array. How is this format even possible?

Comment: @PratyushaTerli it is an array of dictionaries. i.e. an array which comprises of members of type dictionary.

Comment: I is edited now @NSNoob it was "track":["abc":"def","test":"test2"] in this format earlier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the `filter` function

```
let queueID27Exists = !array.filter({$0["QueueId"] as? Int == 27}).isEmpty
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for your previous JSON object!

```
if let results : NSDictionary = post.objectForKey("data") as? NSDictionary {
     let array:NSArray = (results.valueForKey("track") as! NSArray)
     if "25" == array[0].valueForKey("trackID") as? String {
         NSLog("YES")
     } else {
         NSLog("NO")
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var found = false    
for (_, data) in post {
    let track = data["track"]
    if track["trackID"] == "25" {
        found = true
    }
```

Comment: i have array of tracks

Comment: Then you just need to iterate through them with `for`

Comment: Is it an array of "data" or an array of "track"? Can you show me an example with two tracks? I can't follow the structure.