# NSObject subclass in Swift: hash vs hashValue, isEqual vs ==

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsobject

When subclassing `NSObject` in Swift, should you override `hash` or implement `Hashable`?

Also, should you override `isEqual:` or implement the `==` operator?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

`NSObject` already conforms to the `Hashable` protocol:

```
extension NSObject : Equatable, Hashable {
    /// The hash value.
    ///
    /// **Axiom:** `x == y` implies `x.hashValue == y.hashValue`
    ///
    /// - Note: the hash value is not guaranteed to be stable across
    ///   different invocations of the same program.  Do not persist the
    ///   hash value across program runs.
    public var hashValue: Int { get }
}

public func ==(lhs: NSObject, rhs: NSObject) -> Bool
```

I could not find an official reference, but it seems that `hashValue`
calls the `hash` method from `NSObjectProtocol`, and `==` calls the
`isEqual:` method (from the same protocol). **See update at the
end of the answer!**

For `NSObject` subclasses, the correct way seems to be
to override `hash` and `isEqual:`, and here is an experiment which
demonstrates that:

#### 1. Override `hashValue` and `==`

```
class ClassA : NSObject {
    let value : Int
    
    init(value : Int) {
        self.value = value
        super.init()
    }
    
    override var hashValue : Int {
        return value
    }
}

func ==(lhs: ClassA, rhs: ClassA) -> Bool {
    return lhs.value == rhs.value
}
```

Now create two different instances of the class which are considered
"equal" and put them into a set:

```
let a1 = ClassA(value: 13)
let a2 = ClassA(value: 13)

let nsSetA = NSSet(objects: a1, a2)
let swSetA = Set([a1, a2])

print(nsSetA.count) // 2
print(swSetA.count) // 2
```

As you can see, both `NSSet` and `Set` treat the objects as different.
This is not the desired result. Arrays have unexpected results as well:

```
let nsArrayA = NSArray(object: a1)
let swArrayA = [a1]

print(nsArrayA.indexOfObject(a2)) // 9223372036854775807 == NSNotFound
print(swArrayA.indexOf(a2)) // nil
```

Setting breakpoints or adding debug output reveals that the overridden
`==` operator is never called. I don't know if this is a bug or
intended behavior.

#### 2. Override `hash` and `isEqual:`

```
class ClassB : NSObject {
    let value : Int
    
    init(value : Int) {
        self.value = value
        super.init()
    }
    
    override var hash : Int {
        return value
    }
    
    override func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        if let other = object as? ClassB {
            return self.value == other.value
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

For **Swift 3,** the definition of `isEqual:` changed to

```
override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool { ... }
```

Now all results are as expected:

```
let b1 = ClassB(value: 13)
let b2 = ClassB(value: 13)

let nsSetB = NSSet(objects: b1, b2)
let swSetB = Set([b1, b2])

print(swSetB.count) // 1
print(nsSetB.count) // 1

let nsArrayB = NSArray(object: b1)
let swArrayB = [b1]

print(nsArrayB.indexOfObject(b2)) // 0
print(swArrayB.indexOf(b2)) // Optional(0)
```

---

**Update:** The behavior is documented in the book "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C", under "Interacting with Objective-C API":

> The default implementation of the `==` operator invokes the `isEqual:` method, and the default implementation of the `===` operator checks pointer equality. You should not override the equality or identity operators for types imported from Objective-C.
>
> The base implementation of the `isEqual:` provided by the `NSObject` class is equivalent to an identity check by pointer equality. You can override `isEqual:` in a subclass to have Swift and Objective-C APIs determine equality based on the contents of objects rather than their identities.

The book is available in the Apple Book app.

It was also documented on Apple's website but was removed, and is still visible on the [WebArchive snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20160310184302/https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID51) of the page.

Comment: Thanks! This is excellent. Surprised that the overrides don't even work with Swift data structures.

Comment: You do not have to overwrite `-hash`, but `-isEqual:` only. Obviously there is no good implementation of `-hash` for all mutable classes. The only possible implementation is to return a constant (i. e. the address of the class object or a magic number.) Moreover, having mutable classes in a set it is impossible to fulfill the expectations of using a set (no two instances are equal). This is one of the reasons why equity and identity are congruent in Core Data.

Comment: This is the correct answer and a useful piece of information for any practical Swift programmer.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad at least in Swift 2.2, you *do* need to override both `hash` and `-isEqual:`

Answer (score 10):

For `NSObject` it is best to override `hash` and `isEqual`. It already conforms to `Hashable` and `Equatable` and has synthesized conformances for that which in turn invoke `hash` and `isEqual`. So since it is an `NSObject`, do it the ObjC way and override the values that also affect the ObjC hash value and equality.

```
class Identity: NSObject {

    let name: String
    let email: String

    init(name: String, email: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
    }

    override var hash: Int {
        var hasher = Hasher()
        hasher.combine(name)
        hasher.combine(email)
        return hasher.finalize()
    }

    override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
        guard let other = object as? Identity else {
            return false
        }
        return name == other.name && email == other.email
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"Also, should you override isEqual: or implement ==?"

You could do both. And in case you'd make the implementations
behave differently you'd add flare to the life of the users of your code too. Been there, done that. It's fun.

Answer (score -3):

Implement `Hashable`, which also requires you to implement the `==` operator for your type. These are used for a lot of useful stuff in the Swift standard library like the `indexOf` function which only works on collections of a type that implements `Equatable`, or the `Set<T>` type which only works with types that implement `Hashable`.