# How to override "==" between objects

Tags: objective-c, swift, set

```
 class Test: NSObject {
    var product_id: String
    var size: String
    var color: String
    var desc: String
    var name: String

    init(arr: [String]) {
        product_id = arr[0]
        size = arr[1]
        color = arr[2]
        desc = arr[3]
        name = arr[4]
    }
}

let t1 = Test(arr: ["1", "S", "Blue", "111", "第一个商品"])
let t2 = Test(arr: ["1", "S", "Blue", "333", "第三个商品"])
let t3 = Test(arr: ["1", "S", "Blue", "666", "第六个商品"])
let t4 = Test(arr: ["1", "S", "Blue", "777", "第七个商品"])

let t5 = Test(arr: ["2", "S", "Blue", "222", "第二个商品"])
let t6 = Test(arr: ["2", "S", "Blue", "555", "第五个商品"])

let t7 = Test(arr: ["3", "S", "Blue", "444", "第四个商品"])

let initialSWSet = Set([t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7])
initialSWSet.count
```

I expect initialSWSet.count == 3, in other words , if a test's product_id, size, color is same the test is same。   t1 == t2 == t3 == t4; t5 == t6; t7
how can i achieve the work? 
Thank advance!

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: We know in Swift, a custom class (not a NSObject subclass) support Set may implement Hashable & Equable protocols by self, but my class is a NSObject subclass. How can i achieve same work?

Comment: Change the title of your question. "=" is assignment, not comparison.

Comment: You *can* implement Hashable/Equatable in your NSObject subclass, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319959/nsobject-subclass-in-swift-hash-vs-hashvalue-isequal-vs.

Comment: Thanks, i achieve it  by override hash property and isEqul function @MartinR

Comment: More simple, you can convert your object to nsdata and compair "==" between 2 nsdata