# Swift doesn't call my "==" operator overload when I extend CollectionType

Tags: swift, equatable

I have a custom class (VotingOption) which inherits from `NSManagedObject` and sometimes I want to check if some voting options within an array are duplicates. I am trying to make my code as general as possible. This is what I did to extend the CollectionType protocol:

```
extension CollectionType where Self.Generator.Element : Equatable {

    var duplicates: [Self.Generator.Element]{
        return = self.filter { element in
            return self.filter { $0 == element }.count != 1
        }
    }

    var hasDuplicates: Bool {
        return (self.duplicates.count != 0)
    }
}
```

this is working like a charm, except that it is not using the global function:

```
func ==(lhs: VotingOption, rhs: VotingOption) -> Bool {
     return (lhs.location?.title.lowercaseString == rhs.location?.title.lowercaseString) && (lhs.startDate == rhs.startDate)
}
```

when I do something like this:

```
let temp: [VotingOption] = votingOptions?.array as? [VotingOption]
if temp.hasDuplicates {
     //do something
}
```

When I extend isEqual in VotingOption like this:

```
class VotingOption: NSManagedObject {

    override func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool {

        if let rhs = object as? VotingOption {
            return (self.location?.title.lowercaseString == rhs.location?.title.lowercaseString) && (self.startDate == rhs.startDate)
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
    ...
    ...
    ... rest of class
}
```

The app crashes and it points at the AppDelegate with a "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException" error

How to tell the "==" in CollectionType to use the global function of VotingOption?

Comment: at first CollectionType is protocol, not a class! the rest of your question is not very clear, at least for me. what is your expectation and why?

Comment: Does `VotingOption` inherit from `NSObject`? In that case you have to override `isEqual`, see [NSObject subclass in Swift: hash vs hashValue, isEqual vs ==](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319959/nsobject-subclass-in-swift-hash-vs-hashvalue-isequal-vs).

Comment: @MartinR Yes it inherits from NSObject. I have tried overriding the isEqual but it kept crashing. I have edited the question. Please check out the additions

Comment: OK, so this is a NSManagedObject subclass. The documentation states that you must not override `isEqual:` on NSManagedObject subclasses. It seems that you are out of luck ...

Comment: can you provide a link that confirms this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all those who helped. I will post final implementation here:
Basically created a new protocol "Identity" with a method "equals" which is basically "==" and finally added a generic extension for NSManagedObjects that implement "Identity" which basically does "==" in the "equals" method. However in "VotingOption" I have overrided this function for my specific needs. Finally, the collection type was extended where the "Element" is "Identity". instead of "==" it calls the "equals" method :)

```
protocol Identity {
     func equals(rhs: Self) -> Bool
}

extension Identity where Self: NSManagedObject {
     func equals(rhs: Self) -> Bool {
          return self == rhs
     }
}

extension CollectionType where Self.Generator.Element : Identity {

    var duplicates: [Self.Generator.Element] {

        return self.filter { element in
            return self.filter { $0.equals(element) }.count != 1
        }
    }

    var hasDuplicates: Bool {
        return (self.duplicates.count > 0)
    }
}

class VotingOption: NSManagedObject, Identity {

    func equals(rhs: VotingOption) -> Bool {

    //... implementation here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that implements the `duplicates` and `hasDuplicates` twice, once for `Equatable` elements, and once for your `VotingOptions` class. In order to reduce code duplication as much as possible, I've defined a generic implementation for finding duplicates that allows you to pass a function/closure that compares the two elements:

```
extension CollectionType {

    func findDuplicates(checkEqual: (Self.Generator.Element, Self.Generator.Element) -> Bool) -> [Self.Generator.Element]{
        return self.filter { element in
            return self.filter { checkEqual($0, element) }.count != 1
        }
    }
}

extension CollectionType where Self.Generator.Element : Equatable {

    var duplicates: [Self.Generator.Element]{
        return self.findDuplicates(==)
    }

    var hasDuplicates: Bool {
        return (self.duplicates.count != 0)
    }
}

extension CollectionType where Self.Generator.Element : VotingOption {

    var duplicates: [Self.Generator.Element]{
        return self.findDuplicates {lhs, rhs in
            return (lhs.location?.title.lowercaseString == rhs.location?.title.lowercaseString) && (lhs.startDate == rhs.startDate)
        }
    }

    var hasDuplicates: Bool {
        return (self.duplicates.count != 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: THANKS! Actually I ended up with a different implementation (somewhat similar to you). I'll accept your answer since it is the closest to what I needed. The main thing was that it isn't as "generic" as I needed. I'll update my question