# Set doesn't work for NSManagedObject?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, set, nsset

I found it recently in my program, the duplications are not stopped, even I used the Set. 
The object is called Category, with two variables.

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension Category {
    @NSManaged var name: String?
    @NSManaged var items: NSSet?
}
class Category: NSManagedObject {
    override var hashValue: Int {
    return name!.hashValue
    }
}
func == (left: Category, right: Category) -> Bool {
     return left.name == right.name
}
```

I have override the hashValue: Int and the == method in the class, but the Set still consider them as two objects. Does that mean Set doesn't work for NSManagedObjects or I have something left need to be done?

Here is my unit test code:

```
    guard let cate1 = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Category", inManagedObjectContext: context) as? MyProgram.Category else { return }
    cate1.name = "Cate"
    cate1.items = nil
    guard let cate2 = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Category", inManagedObjectContext: context) as? MyProgram.Category else { return }
    cate2.name = "Cate"
    cate2.items = nil
    let combine = Set<MyProgram.Category>([cate1, cate2])
    assert(cate1.hashValue == cate2.hashValue)
    assert(combine.count == 1)
```

It will fail at the last line of code.
Can anybody who knows the reason gives me some advices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you are trying to do is not possible with Core Data
managed objects.

- For subclasses of `NSObject`, you would have to override `isEqual:` and  `hash` (instead of `==` and `hashValue`), see [NSObject subclass in Swift: hash vs hashValue, isEqual vs ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319959/nsobject-subclass-in-swift-hash-vs-hashvalue-isequal-vs).
- For `NSManagedObject` subclasses, it is explicitly "forbidden" to
  override `isEqual:` and `hash`, see [NSManagedObject Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/). The reason is
  that you can compare managed objects for equality without retrieving all their 
  properties from the persistent store ("fire a fault").

As a consequence you cannot define your own notion of "equality"
for Core Data managed objects in a way that it works with `Set` or
`NSSet`.

To check if a set already contains a managed object with a given
property you can do something like

```
if (combine.contains { $0.name == cate2.name }) {

}
```

In order to avoid Category objects with the same name, you would have
to execute a fetch request which checks if an object with the given
name already exists.

Comment: Thank you so much, it helps!