# Swift 2.0 Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter cannot be represented in Objective-C

Tags: swift

After I have updated Swift 1 to Swift 2.0 I have an issue.

I am getting the following error on the first line of this code:

> Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter cannot be represented in Objective-C

```
@objc func personsToFirstStep(persons: [Person]) {
    for person in persons {
        if !self.persons.contains(person) && person.id != userID {
            self.persons.append(person)
        }
    }

    collectionView.reloadData()
    collectionViewPlaceholder.hidden = true
    collectionView.hidden = false
    collectionGradientView.hidden = false
}
```

This this Person class:

```
class Person: Hashable {

    var intID: Int = 0
    var id: String = ""
    var name: String = ""
    var type: String = ""

    var hashValue: Int {
        return self.intID
    }

    init(id: String, name: String, type: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.intID = Int(id)!
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
    }

}

func ==(lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
    return lhs.intID == rhs.intID
}
```

Comment: Can Person inherit from NSObject?

Comment: What's `Person`? Also please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37256261/edit) with your code, rather than posting it as a comment or screenshot. Screenshots can be helpful to show where the problem is, but should never be a replacement for the actual code – as outside links can break and others cannot easily use it.

Comment: Person is a class)

Comment: Person MUST be inherited from NSObject!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You have very nicely explained the problem yourself:

```
class Person: Hashable {
```

Person is not an NSObject. But only an NSObject-derived class type can be seen by Objective-C. Therefore your Person type is invisible to Objective-C. But your `@objc func` declaration is for a function that takes an array of Person — and we have just said that Person is invisible to Objective-C. So your `@objc func` declaration is illegal. Objective-C cannot be shown this function, because it cannot be shown its parameter.

You would need to change your class declaration to start like this:

```
class Person: NSObject {
```

...and then you might of course have to make any necessary further adjustments in the class's implementation. But that change would make your `@objc func` declaration legal. (NSObject *is* Hashable, so the amount of work needed to make this adaptation might not be very great.)

Comment: But what should i do with 

    var hashValue: Int {
        return self.intID
    }

Just delete?

Comment: Yes, but then you will still need to decide how you want hashability / equatability to work for this class. They need to work together. If you don't say what you want to have happen, Cocoa will fall back to object identity, which appears not to be what you want. And you need to do this in the way that Cocoa expects. That is what I meant in my answer by "further adjustments". — See for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/33320737/341994

Answer (score 9):

I was getting this because I declared a class `Notification` of my own and it was messing with Foundation's Notification class.

```
@objc func playerItemDidReachEnd(notification: Notification) {...}
```

So I changed it to Foundation.Notification

```
@objc func playerItemDidReachEnd(notification: Foundation.Notification) {...}
```

Comment: exactly the same problem I had.

Comment: god bless you, i wouldn't have know the issue because of misleading compiler error which is not smart enough to know that i created a Notification class that conflicts with framework classes.

Answer (score 2):

With this less informations I can only try to suggest you to put this before `Person` declaration.

```
@objc(Person)
class Person {
...
}
```

Comment: we can use @objc when we are calling class... but :NSObject helped a lot ... )