# How can I specify the key and value datatype of an NSDictionary argument in swift?

Tags: swift, objective-c, nsdictionary, swift-dictionary

I would like to define a function in swift that can be used in objective-c as well. I have a enum:

```
    @objc public enum BookType: Int {
      case novel
      case magazine
    
      func name() -> String {
          switch self {
          case .novel:
              return "novel"
          case .magazine:
              return "magazine"
          }
      }
  }
```

And the function is:

```
@objc public func uploadBookImages(images: [BookType: UIImage]) {
       // code here
}
```

This function will bring me an compile error said that:

> Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter cannot
> be represented in Objective-C

It might because objective-c doesn't accept swift dictionary since it is a structure. I am thinking to use NSDictionary instead of a swift dictionary. However, how can I specify the argument data type to [BookType: UIImage] using a NSDictionary? I want to pass a NSDictionary<BookType: UIImage> to the function when I call it.

Comment: Objective C collections can only store objects (as both keys, and values). If you want to use `BookType` as a key, you need to wrap the value into an `NSValue` object. Of course, at that point you lose access to some type safety, because any NSValue can be passed in, not necessarily only those wrapping BookTypes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift 2.0 Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter cannot be represented in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37256261/swift-2-0-method-cannot-be-marked-objc-because-the-type-of-the-parameter-cannot)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use NSDictionary instead of swift Dictionary

```
  func uploadBookImages(images: NSDictionary) {
    // code here
    print(images)
}
```

Usage:

```
   let dictParams:Dictionary<BookType, Int> = [
        BookType.magazine : 1,
        BookType.novel : 2,
        ];
    
    uploadBookImages(images: dictParams as NSDictionary)
```

Comment: So the answer to the question "How can I specify the key and value datatype of an NSDictionary argument in swift?" is "You can't."?

Comment: Yes ,You Cannot specialize non-generic type 'NSDictionary'

Comment: is there a way to restrict the argument?

Comment: You can handler restriction for the dictParams(Input dictionary).