# func == from equatable protocol does not work for custom object, swift

Tags: ios, swift, equatable

My goal is to show a user list of history logins ( such as username ) if there are any. In order to do that, I am doing

```
1. Create an custom object named User like below

 class User: NSObject
    {
        var login: String

        init(login: String)
        {
            self.login = login
        }
        required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            login = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("login") as! String
        }

        func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
            aCoder.encodeObject(login, forKey: "login")
        }
    }

    // This conform to make sure that I compare the `login` of 2 Users
    func ==(lhs: User, rhs: User) -> Bool
    {
        return lhs.login == rhs.login
    }
```

At UserManager, Im doing `save` and `retrieve` an `User`. Before saving, I'm doing a check if the the list of history logins contains a `User`, I wont add it in, otherwise.

```
class UserManager : NSObject
{
    static let sharedInstance   =   UserManager()
    var userDefaults            =   NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    func saveUser(user:User)
    {
        var users = retrieveAllUsers()

        // Check before adding
        if !(users.contains(user))
        {
            users.append(user)
        }


        let encodedData =   NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(users)
        userDefaults.setObject(encodedData, forKey: "users")
        userDefaults.synchronize()
    }

    func retrieveAllUsers() -> [User]
    {
        guard let data  =   userDefaults.objectForKey("users") as? NSData else
        {
            return [User]()
        }
        let users   =   NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as! [User]
        // Testing purpose
        for user in users
        {
            print(user.login)
        }
        return users
    }
}
```

At first time trying, I do

```
UserManager.sharedInstance.saveUser(User(login: "1234"))
```

Now it saves the first login. At second time, I also do

```
UserManager.sharedInstance.saveUser(User(login: "1234"))
```

UserManager still adds the second login into `nsuserdefault`. That means the function `contains` fails and it leads to

```
func ==(lhs: User, rhs: User) -> Bool
{
    return lhs.login == rhs.login
}
```

does not work properly.

Does anyone know why or have any ideas about this.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319959/nsobject-subclass-in-swift-hash-vs-hashvalue-isequal-vs#

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that User derives from NSObject. This means that (as you rightly say) your `==` implementation is never being consulted. Swift's behavior is different for objects that derive from NSObject; it does things the Objective-C way. To implement equatability on an object that derives from NSObject, override `isEqual:`. That is what makes an NSObject-derived object equatable in a custom way, in both Objective-C and Swift.

Just paste this code right into your User class declaration, and `contains` will start working as you wish:

```
override func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    if let other = object as? User {
        if other.login == self.login {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: thanks. it works. However, i want to fully understand. I know `other` is a new `User`and `self` will be previous `User` which are form the list. My uncertainty is how `self` can be referenced to previous `User` from the list.

Comment: Don't worry about that. After all, you didn't worry about it for `==`. All you need to know is that `contains` depends on this.

Answer (score 3):

### What's going on?

As *@matt* already said, the problem is about equality.

Look

```
var users = [User]()
users.append(User(login: "1234"))
users.contains(User(login: "1234")) // false
```

Look again

```
var users = [User]()
let user = User(login: "1234")
users.append(user)
users.contains(user) // true <---- THIS HAS CHANGED
```

### contains

The contains function is **NOT** using the logic you defined here

```
func ==(lhs: User, rhs: User) -> Bool {
    return lhs.login == rhs.login
}
```

Infact it is simply comparing the memory addresses of the objects.

### Solution

You can solve the issue passing your own logic to `contains`, just replace this

```
if !(users.contains(user)) {
    users.append(user)
}
```

with this

```
if !(users.contains { $0.login == user.login }) {
    users.append(user)
}
```

Comment: I also tried and it works as well. I was surprised  that `contains` logic is used to compare the memory address. Can you explain this line `$0.login == user.login `.What is `$0` means Further more, it seems to be that I dont need to conform `func ==` in my code any more.

Comment: @tonytran: The problem is that you inherit `NSObject` so the `isEqual` method is invoked to check for equality.

Comment: @tonytran: `{ $0.login == user.login }` here `$0` is the n-th element of `users`. This closure is applied to every element of the array until it is `true`. In this case the `contains` returns `true`. Otherwise `contains` does `false`.

Comment: @tonytran: __YES__ `users.contains { $0 == user }` will work fine.

Comment: :please dont shout :). and how is about === ?

Comment: @tonytran: No problem :D This `===` always compare memory addresses