# Difference between Swift's hash and hashValue

Tags: swift, hash, swift-protocols

The `Hashable` protocol in Swift requires you to implement a property called `hashValue`:

```
protocol Hashable : Equatable {
    /// Returns the hash value.  The hash value is not guaranteed to be stable
    /// across different invocations of the same program.  Do not persist the hash
    /// value across program runs.
    ///
    /// The value of `hashValue` property must be consistent with the equality
    /// comparison: if two values compare equal, they must have equal hash
    /// values.
    var hashValue: Int { get }
}
```

However, it seems there's also a similar property called `hash`.

What is the difference between `hash` and `hashValue`?

Comment: `hash` is a property of the [`NSObject` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/), compare [NSObject subclass in Swift: hash vs hashValue, isEqual vs ==](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319959/nsobject-subclass-in-swift-hash-vs-hashvalue-isequal-vs).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`hash` is a required property in the [`NSObject` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/), which groups methods that are fundamental to all Objective-C objects, so that predates Swift.
The default implementation just returns the objects address,
as one can see in 
[NSObject.mm](https://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/NSObject.mm), but one can override the property
in `NSObject` subclasses.

`hashValue` is a required property of the Swift `Hashable` protocol.

Both are connected via a `NSObject` extension defined in the
Swift standard library in
[ObjectiveC.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/ObjectiveC/ObjectiveC.swift):

```
extension NSObject : Equatable, Hashable {
  /// The hash value.
  ///
  /// **Axiom:** `x == y` implies `x.hashValue == y.hashValue`
  ///
  /// - Note: the hash value is not guaranteed to be stable across
  ///   different invocations of the same program.  Do not persist the
  ///   hash value across program runs.
  open var hashValue: Int {
    return hash
  }
}

public func == (lhs: NSObject, rhs: NSObject) -> Bool {
  return lhs.isEqual(rhs)
}
```

(For the meaning of `open var`, see [What is the 'open' keyword in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38947101/what-is-an-open-var-in-swift).)

So `NSObject` (and all subclasses) conform to the `Hashable`
protocol, and the default `hashValue` implementation
return the `hash` property of the object.

A similar relationship exists between the `isEqual` method of the
`NSObject` protocol, and the `==` operator from the `Equatable`
protocol: `NSObject` (and all subclasses) conform to the `Equatable`
protocol, and the default `==` implementation
calls the `isEqual:` method on the operands.

Comment: "Do not persist the hash value across program runs." ... would have been useful to know lol ... just wasted 2 hours wondering why my persisted hashes were not the same

Comment: @quemeful: It was always *documented* as non-persistent, but only as of Swift 4.2 this is actively enforced in the Swift library by using a per-execution random seed, compare https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0206-hashable-enhancements.md#the-hasher-struct .

Comment: It appears `hash` is persistent (at least used from objective c) and `hashValue` isn't.

Comment: @DeclanMcKenna: `hashValue` and `hash` should return the same value for `NSObject` subclasses (the memory address) unless overridden in a subclass. That memory address *can* be the same across multiple runs of the program, but you can not rely on it.