# "Cannot inherit from non-open class" swift

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8-beta6

As of Xcode 8 beta 6 I now get the compile error "Cannot inherit from non-open class (Class)" outside of its defining module"

The class I was inheriting from was part of a separate Swift framework but my project compiled for Xcode 8 beta 5. What do I need to change to get my project to compile again?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38947101/what-is-an-open-var-in-swift

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Found the answer myself.

In Swift 3 you can now mark a class as `open` instead of `public` this allows files outside of the module to subclass that class.

Simply replace `public` in your module class with `open`.

Reference [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0117-non-public-subclassable-by-default.md).

Comment: Also documented in the Xcode 8 beta 6 Release Notes.

Answer (score 33):

The class you inherit from needs to be defined as `open` instead of `public`.

A bit more context on the changes to access control in Swift 3:

Swift 2 only had 3 access levels:

- `private`: entities are available only from within the source file where they are defined.
- `internal`: entities are available to the entire module that includes the definition.
- `public`: entities are intended for use as API, and can be accessed by any file that imports the module.

Swift 3 is adding 2 more access levels (`open` and `fileprivate`) and changing the meaning of `private`:

- `private`: symbol visible within the current declaration only.
- `fileprivate`: symbol visible within the current file.
- `internal`: symbol visible within the current module or default access modifier.
- `public`: symbol visible outside the current module.
- `open`: for class or function to be subclassed or overridden outside the current module.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error even after marking the class as `open` (on Xcode 14.1). The fix was a clean (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>) and rebuild.