# Xcode 8: Cannot inherit from non-open class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

After I updated to latest Xcode 8, I get this error:

> Cannot inherit from non-open class ‘WDBaseViewController’ outside of its defining module

My class is declared like this

```
public class ProfileViewController: WDBaseViewController {
}
```

But I didn’t change the framework.

Comment: The base class `WDBaseViewController` needs to be defined as `open` instead of `public` in the framework you are using.

Comment: See also [What is the 'open' keyword in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38947101/what-is-the-open-keyword-in-swift),  and the Xcode 8 beta 6 Release Notes.

Comment: Yes, I found it. Thanks.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Short answer:**

To be able to subclass it, the base class `WDBaseViewController` needs to be defined as `open` instead of `public` in the framework you are using.

```
open class WDBaseViewController {
    ...
}
```

If it’s an internal framework you can do it yourself, otherwise you will have to wait for the author to support Swift 3.

**Long answer:**

Swift 3 is bringing significant changes to access control.

Swift 2 only had 3 access levels:

- `private`: entities are available only from within the source file where they are defined.
- `internal`: entities are available to the entire module that includes the definition.
- `public`: entities are intended for use as API, and can be accessed by any file that imports the module.

Swift 3 is adding 2 more access levels (`open` and `fileprivate`) and changing the meaning of `private`:

- `private`: symbol visible within the current declaration only.
- `fileprivate`: symbol visible within the current file.
- `internal`: symbol visible within the current module.
- `public`: symbol visible outside the current module.
- `open`: for class or function to be subclassed or overridden outside the current module.

Comment: Hi Yann, which access level to choose is also driven by testing requirements.  When you use '@testable import' in unit tests it does not allow access to private or fileprivate symbols.  It does open up access to internal symbols