# prefersStatusBarHidden, preferredStatusBarStyle properties in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3, xcode8

Starting Swift 3 / iOS 10, methods such as **preferredStatusBarStyle** and **prefersStatusBarHidden** became:

```
    @available(iOS 7.0, *)
    open var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle { get }

    @available(iOS 7.0, *)
    open var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool { get }
```

As such existing code that used to override the methods no longer builds. Given these properties are readonly, how can you assign them a value / override them?

Comment: *"As such existing code that used to override the methods no longer builds."* – Are you sure? What error do you get? – `open` means that you *can* override the property in your subclass (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38947101/what-is-the-open-keyword-in-swift)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to learn that in Swift (since the first public beta pre-1.0), you can override properties. Read-only properties can be overridden like this:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return yourPreferredStatusBarStyle
}
```

Comment: How to do in ObjC?

Answer (score 0):

Now you'll need to Override the property:

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool{
    get{
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override  preferredStatusBarStyle in Your Viewcontroller

like this

```
 override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
```