# Does the initializer of an `open` class need to be open as well?

Tags: swift, keyword, swift3

Swift 3 introduced the new [open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38947101/what-is-the-open-keyword-in-swift) keyword that I'm using in a framework.

Does an `open` class in this framework require an `open` initialiser to be used outside of said framework, or does the init function inherit the `open` declaration on the class?

For example:

```
open class OpenClass {
    var A: String

    init() {           // does this init() function need to be marked open?
        A = String()
    }
}
```

*Side question: do the variables in the open class `OpenClass` inherit the open nature of their class?*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [SE-0117 Allow distinguishing between public access and public overridability](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0117-non-public-subclassable-by-default.md):

> Initializers do not participate in open checking; they cannot be declared open, and there are no restrictions on providing an initializer that has the same signature as an initializer in the superclass.

You need not and you *cannot* declare a init method as open:

```
open class OpenClass {

    open init() { // error: only classes and overridable class members can be declared 'open'; use 'public'

    }
}
```

The default access level for all members of a class (properties
and methods) is *internal,* that applies to open classes as well.