# Is it possible to edit the value of a public variable from another module?

Tags: swift, module, public, access-control

Can you edit the value of a public variable from another module or does that variable have to be open.

---

My understanding of public/open in swift 3 is:

- Public classes can be made in another module but only open classes can be subclassed in another module.
- Public functions can be called in another module but only open functions can be overwritten in another module.
- But I am unsure about about variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most definitely can! Here is a great way you can accomplish it:

In the module that contains the variable that you wish to manipulate:

```
// Must be declared globally
public var someValue = "hi"
```

In a different module that you wish to manipulate the variable from:

```
// Initialize the module that holds the variable you want to manipulate
var myModule = SomeModule()

// Manipulate the variable (someValue)
myModule.someValue = "bye"
```

The variable `someValue` will now have a value of "bye"

Comment: Really appreciate this, Would that mean there's no difference between a open var and public var? (and the difference between open and public is just for functions and classes)

Comment: Actually there are minor differences between `public` and `open` vars, the main one being `open` vars are subclass-able outside the module while `public` vars are not. @Martin R does a great job of explaining it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38947101/what-is-the-open-keyword-in-swift