# Swift 3: Tableview datasource methods "Overriding non-open instance method outside of its defining module" error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, inheritance, ios-frameworks

I have an `open` `BaseViewController` class in core framework that has tableview datasource methods implemented. Let's say I've another class (outside the module) `ClassA` with `BaseViewController` as it's superclass. When I try to override tableview datasource methods, it's throwing this error `Overriding non-open instance method outside of its defining module`.

`BaseViewController` looks like this

```
open class BaseViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

...

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 0
}

public func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 0
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return UITableViewCell()
  }
}
```

ClassA

```
import CustomCoreFramework

class ClassA : BaseViewController {

// throws an error
public override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return tableViewListItems.count
}

}
```

I suppose the `open` class methods should be accessible outside the module. I tried changing the tableview methods access specifiers to `public` and different combinations but nothing seems to work.

Comment: may be because methods are marked public try removing public once and check, not sure though haven't tried this before.

Comment: You have to inherit `BaseViewController` – as the name seems to imply – from **UIViewController** rather than from `UITableViewDelegate`

Comment: Should the BaseViewController’s methods be declared open?

Comment: @vadian  Yes I'm doing that, just forgot to put it in the post. I've updated the post. Please check.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The BaseViewController’s methods should be declared open. 
This is discuss in the thread in reference.

See [What is the 'open' keyword in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38947101/what-is-the-open-keyword-in-swift)

Comment: I tried that before, it didn't work but now it did. I don't know why!! I'm glad that it worked and also pissed because it didn't work before. Thanks anyway.