# How is the hashValue generated for UIViewController in Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift4.2, hashable

I'm wondering if I can use the hashValue of an UIViewController to uniquely identify an instance of a UIViewController during runtime.

I tried to create a UIViewController and modify some of its properties and the hasValue stays the same. 
It seems like the hashValue is not changing during runtime but I want to be sure and I didn't find 'how its been generated' in the documentation.

Does anyone know if its based on the starting memoryAddress?
Can the hashValue change during runtime?

Comment: UIViewController inherits from NSObject, and its hash value *is* the memory address (compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/38946892/1187415). And it is a reference type, therefore changing the properties does not mutate the reference.

Comment: awesome! Thx a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Swift's hash and hashValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38946690/difference-between-swifts-hash-and-hashvalue)