# Can't use Hashable while encoding nsarray of custom objects

Tags: arrays, swift, nsobject, nscoding, hashable

I have a custom class for mapping like below.

```
class UserSaved {

    var Id         : String
    var UserName   : String
    var profileURL      : String
    var fullNameUser    : String

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(self.Id, forKey: "Id")
        aCoder.encode(self.UserName, forKey: "UserName")
        aCoder.encode(self.profileURL, forKey: "profileURL")
        aCoder.encode(self.fullNameUser, forKey: "fullNameUser")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.Id = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "Id") as! String
        self.UserName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "UserName") as! String
        self.profileURL = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "profileURL") as! String
        self.fullNameUser = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "fullNameUser") as! String

       // self.init(my_id: self.Id, my_username: self.UserName, profile_url: self.profileURL, full_name: self.fullNameUser)
    }

    init(my_id: String, my_username: String, profile_url: String, full_name : String) {
        self.Id = my_id
        self.UserName = my_username
        self.profileURL = profile_url
        self.fullNameUser = full_name
    }
}
```

Now I am adding the different model object into two different arrays like below, below both arrays may have some common entries

```
//////array 1
let arrayTemp = dic.value(forKey: "data") as! NSArray
for i in 0..<arrayTemp.count {
    let dic = arrayTemp.object(at: i) as! NSDictionary
    let strId = String(dic.value(forKey: "pk") as! Int)
    let instaName = dic.value(forKey: "username") as! String
    let profileURL = dic.value(forKey: "profile_pic_url") as! String
    let fullName = dic.value(forKey: "full_name") as! String
    let person1 = UserSaved(insta_id: strId, insta_username: instaName,profile_url: profileURL,full_name: fullName)
    self.arr1.append(person1)
}

//////array 2
let arrayTemp = dic.value(forKey: "data") as! NSArray
for i in 0..<arrayTemp.count {
    let dic = arrayTemp.object(at: i) as! NSDictionary
    let strId = String(dic.value(forKey: "pk") as! Int)
    let instaName = dic.value(forKey: "username") as! String
    let profileURL = dic.value(forKey: "profile_pic_url") as! String
    let fullName = dic.value(forKey: "full_name") as! String
    let person2 = UserSaved(insta_id: strId, insta_username: instaName,profile_url: profileURL,full_name: fullName)
    self.arr2.append(person2)
}
```

Now I am manupalting above arrays using below code, which works fine

```
let setA = Set(self.arr1)
let setB = Set(self.arr2)
let inBothAAndB = setA.intersection(setB)
let inAButNotB = setA.subtracting(setB)
let inBButNotA = setB.subtracting(setA)
```

Now when I tried to save the array into userdefaults using `NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData`. It gives me error like below

```
2018-10-09 12:27:46.375587+0530 Insta_Analytics[12764:181604] *** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x6100000f0500 of class 
'Insta_Analytics.UserSaved' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
Unrecognized selector -[Insta_Analytics.UserSaved replacementObjectForKeyedArchiver:]
2018-10-09 12:27:46.376141+0530 Insta_Analytics[12764:181604] 
Unrecognized selector -[Insta_Analytics.UserSaved replacementObjectForKeyedArchiver:]
```

Here is my code of saving array into `userdefaults`

```
                        let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self.arr1)
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: "arr_store")
```

Now if I change my custom mapping model `UserSaved` inherit from `NSCoding` and `NSObject`. It works, but that time manipulating data is not working

SO at one time, only one thing works. I want to save my arrays using `NSCoding` while at the same time `intersection` and `subtracting` should work

Comment: can you post the code where you save the array into userdefaults?

Comment: @AndreiDurnea:see update code in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `NSCoder` the class must be a subclass of `NSObject`

```
class UserSaved : NSObject, NSCoding {
```

---

But in your case I recommend to use `Codable` and add the conformance to `Equatable`

```
class UserSaved : Codable, Equatable {
```

Delete the `init(coder` and `encode(with` methods and serialize the data

```
let encodedData = PropertyListEncoder().encode(self.arr1)
```

And don't use `NSArray / NSDictionary` in Swift. Use native types. And don't use `value(forKey`. Use key subscripting.

To decode the data use

```
if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "arr_store") {
    do {
        let array = try PropertyListDecoder().decode([UserSaved].self, from: data)

    } catch { print(error) }
}
```

Comment: I know. But if I use that I can not subtract 2 arrays using Hashable

Comment: @Nirav: Subclasses of NSObject  must override `hash` and `isEqual:`, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/33319959/1187415

Comment: @MartinR : I tried your solution. But not able to subtracting or intersection two arrays.

Comment: @vadian : let me check your solution too

Comment: @vadian: How to decode the encoded data which was encoded by Codable ?

Comment: I updated the answer. You can even use a struct, a class is not mandatory.

Comment: @vadian: Your code works man !! You are genius... Thanks a lot... I will ask in future if stuck at any point regarding this matter :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Update your class UserSaved to implement the following:

```
class UserSaved: NSObject, NSCoding, Hashable {
// ...
```