# Override Equatable and Hashable in Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject, hashable, equatable

Is there a way to override Equatable of NSManagedObject?  I have a coredata dataset of 300k objects and I need to remove duplicates base on the object's business id.

```
// Coredata NSManagedObject
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Business)
public class Business: NSManagedObject {

}
```

override error message:

[image]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319959/nsobject-subclass-in-swift-hash-vs-hashvalue-isequal-vs

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Since `NSManagedObject` already conforms to `Equatable`, why do you bother to conform to it again? :)
Just override the `==` function and you are good to go!

```
extension Business {
    static func == (lhs: Business, rhs: Business) -> Bool {
        print("custom equation has been called")
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

You can test it like so:

```
var b1 = Business()
var b2 = Business()
b1.id = "1"
b2.id = "2"

print("b1 == b2 ? \(b1 == b2)")
```

The result printed out proves your custom `==` function get called.

```
custom equation has been called
b1 == b2 ? false
```

Comment: This is invalid. You need to also override the implementation of `func hash(into:)`, otherwise you'll be violating the contract of `Hashable` (that equal values have equivalent hashes)

Comment: [Methods and Properties You Must Not Override](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject#overview)

checkout above link, which says you MUST not override == in NSManagedObject.

also, something like this can be useful if you want unique results.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchrequest/1506344-returnsdistinctresults

Comment: It is bad practise to override a method via an extension as it's not clear what will get executed; the original or the extension.

Answer (score 4):

`NSManagedObject` already declares that it conforms to both `Equatable` and `Hashable`. No need to add the `: Equatable`.

You need to override the associated methods directly in your `Business` class without using the extension.

Comment: Was it `==` that needs to be implemented, or [`NSObjectProtocol.isEqual(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobjectprotocol/1418795-isequal)? I can never remember it right