# Can't fix hashability for a class derived from NSObject

Tags: swift, hash

```
final class Foo: NSObject, NSFileProviderItem
{
    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher)
    {
        hasher.combine(itemIdentifier)
    }
}
```

yields swift compiler errors:

Overriding non-open instance method outside of its defining module

Overriding declarations in extensions is not supported

Is there a way to fix NSObject hashability?
I get duplicates of Foo instances in Sets which is precisely
what I want to avoid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/33319959/1187415: NSObject subclasses must override `hash` and `isEqual:`

Comment: looks like this needs closing as a dup indeed.

Answer (score 4):

Found the fix here:

https://forums.swift.org/t/xcode-10-gm-hash-into-issue-from-nsobject-class/16141/2

```
public override var hash: Int {
    var hasher = Hasher()
    hasher.combine(itemIdentifier)
    return hasher.finalize()
}
```

this seems to be a dup of [NSObject subclass in Swift: hash vs hashValue, isEqual vs ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319959/nsobject-subclass-in-swift-hash-vs-hashvalue-isequal-vs)