# Swift - What is the difference between implementing Hashable and Equatable and NSObject hash and isEqual overrides

Tags: ios, swift, hashable, equatable, nsdiffabledatasourcesnapshot

I'm trying to wrap my head around the new `DiffableDataSource` way of handling data in tableviews/collectionviews and during testing I came across a strange crash.
I would expect that the two implementations below would work exactly the same:

Implementation 1:

```swift
class DiffableSection {

    var id: String
    var items: [AnyDiffable]

    init(id: String,
         items: [AnyDiffable] = []) {
        self.id = id
        self.items = items
    }
}

extension DiffableSection: Hashable {
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
}

extension DiffableSection: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: DiffableSection, rhs: DiffableSection) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

Implementation 2:

```swift
class DiffableSection: NSObject {

    var id: String
    var items: [AnyDiffable]

    init(id: String,
         items: [AnyDiffable] = []) {
        self.id = id
        self.items = items
    }

    // MARK: - Hashable and Equatable

    public override var hash: Int {
        var hasher = Hasher()
        hasher.combine(id)
        return hasher.finalize()
    }

    public override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
        guard let object = object as? DiffableSection else { return false }
        return id == object.id
    }
}
```

but apparently they are not - `Implementation 2` works with the code below and `Implementation 1` does not.

```swift
    func apply(_ sections: [DiffableSection]) {
        var snapshot = self.snapshot()
        for section in sections {
            snapshot.appendSectionIfNeeded(section)
            snapshot.appendItems(section.items, toSection: section)
        }
        apply(snapshot)
    }

(...)
extension NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot {
    mutating func appendSectionIfNeeded(_ identifier: SectionIdentifierType) {
        if sectionIdentifiers.contains(identifier) { return }
        appendSections([identifier])
    }
}
```

The crash message I get when running with `Implementation 1`:

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: section != NSNotFound'
```

Can someone explain me what are the differences in those implementations? How could I fix `Implementation 1` to work same as `Implementation 2`??

Comment: Does this answer your question?  [NSObject subclass in Swift: hash vs hashValue, isEqual vs ==](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33319959/1187415).

Comment: @MartinR The link you provided shows me that I indeed need to override `isEqual` to make it work however after reading the highest rated comment I still don't understand what's the difference between `==` :/