# How to properly check if array contains an element inside if statement

Tags: arrays, swift

I have this line of code:

```
   if ((self.datasource?.contains((self.textField?.text)!)) != nil) {
            if let _ = self.placeHolderWhileSelecting {
               // some code
            }
```

Is there more clear way to check if the element contains in array? I have Bool returned by contains function, I dont want to check if this Bool is nil

Edit: the solution is to change array to non-optional type.

Comment: well that is because your datasource is optional,  if your datasource is nil, what do you expect to do?

Comment: Well, KnightOfDragon, you right. changing optional to non-optional do the trick. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if an element is in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102024/how-to-check-if-an-element-is-in-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `if let where` construct. This code prevent crashes if `self.datasource` or `self.textField` are `nil`

```
if let
    list = self.datasource,
    elm = self.textField?.text,
    _ = self.placeHolderWhileSelecting
    where list.contains(elm) {
        // your code
}
```

Comment: Wow! this really elegant solution. Gonna learn more about swift if statement

Comment: @O.G.O Good! A suggestion for the future. Try to avoid the force unwrap (I mean this `!`). It's risky and often there is a safer way to unwrap an optional.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, using optional chaining to get to self.textField.text and assuming datasource remains optional.

```
if let unwrappedArray = self.datasource, let unwrappedString = self.textField?.text {
    if unwrappedArray.contains(unwrappedString) {
        // Some code
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like my proposed solution is similar to one proposed by  appzYourLife above. Concept is generally the same. Unwrap the optionals safely and then, use them.

Comment: Yea, thank you for help, mate. appzYourLife was first so i should to accept his answer