# Search NSObject array for a String using Swift 2

Tags: arrays, search, swift2

In my `Xcode7` `Swift2` project, I have a `Class` called `Recipe` that is of type `NSObject` and `NSCoding` and has a `variable` called `name` that is a `String`:

```
class Recipe: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var name: String

    ...
}
```

This `array` of `names` is displayed in a `TableViewController`.

In a separate `ViewController` the user can add items to this `array` using a `UITextField` and `UIButton`.  I don't want there to be two of the same `names` in the array.  In the `@IBAction` of the `UIButton`, how can I search the array for the typed `name`, checking for duplicates?  In the `ViewController` mentioned above, I reference the `array` as:

```
let recipes = [Recipe]()
```

I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102024/how-to-check-if-an-element-is-in-an-array) and tried:

```
@IBAction func saveReport(sender: UIButton) {

    let checkName = reportName.text!

    if recipes.contains("\(checkName)") {

        print("Found: \(checkName)")

    }

    ...
}
```

But it give an error:

[image]

How can I search the `array` for the typed `name`, using `Swift2`? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array `recipes` contains `Recipe` instances rather than strings.

An easy solution is to use the filter function to filter for a recipe with the string value in `checkName`

```
if !recipes.filter({$0.name == checkName}).isEmpty {
  print("Found: \(checkName)")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `contains` but you have to give it a predicate instead of just the string you're searching:

```
if recipes.contains( { $0.name == checkName } ) {
    print("Found: \(checkName)")
}
```