# Matching multiple enums with a single guard case?

Tags: swift, enums

I want to match against multiple enums and have something like this:

```
guard case .north = $0, case .south = $0 else { return }
```

Is there a way to condense this to a single statement like this?

```
guard case (. north, . south) = $0 else { return }
```

The above does not compile, but was hoping I can do something like this. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do if pattern matching with multiple cases?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39333716/how-to-do-if-pattern-matching-with-multiple-cases)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can put the desired cases into a literal array and use `contains` to test for a match:

```
guard [.north, .south].contains($0) else { return }
```