# How can I pattern match with the OR operator on an enum with associated values?

Tags: swift, enums, pattern-matching

I have this enum:

```
enum Foo {
    case a(x: Int)
    case b(x: Int)
    case c
    case d
}
```

and `foo`

```
let foo = Foo.a(x: 10)
```

I want to check if `foo` is *either* `a`, `b` or `c`, regardless of what `x` is.

With a switch statement, I could do:

```
switch foo {
case .a, .b, .c:
    ...
case .d:
    break
}
```

but it's a bit long winded.

I thought I could do the same with `if case`:

```
if case .a, .b, .c = foo { ... }
```

This produced a compiler error.

I then found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39333716/how-to-do-if-pattern-matching-with-multiple-cases), and tried this:

```
if [Foo.a, Foo.b, Foo.c].contains(foo) { ... }
```

The compiler thought the array was of type `[Any]`, so this doesn't work either...

What can I do except extracting it as a method and calling that method? Is there something new in Swift 4.2 that solves this?

Comment: Doing it with an `if` ;-) ... `if ({ switch foo { case .a, .b, .c: return true; default: return false }}()) {
    print("match")
}`

Comment: There is nothing new Swift 4.2 with regard to this topic.

Comment: `case .a, .b` is also incorrect, because they need input.

Comment: @AnkitThakur I can do `.a, .b` in a switch statement though

Comment: @Sweeper Your problem there when using the contains approach is that Foo it is not equatable. Also `Foo.a` it is not even a valid syntax for your structure `Foo.a(x: 1)`

Comment: So you just need to declare `enum Foo: Equatable {` and when calling `if [Foo.a(x: 1), Foo.b(x: 2), Foo.c].contains(foo) {`

Comment: @LeoDabus I want the test to be true for all `x`, not just `2` and `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift doesn't support that because `Foo` instances need pattern matching, as they are not `Equatable`. And the only separator that allows multiple pattern matches is `,`, and that operator corresponds to an `and` operation, you can't have `or`'s.

One ugly (and I'd say incorrect, or misleading) approach would be to add conformance to `Equatable` and ignore the associated values:

```swift
enum Foo: Equatable {
    case a(x: Int)
    case b(x: Int)
    case c
    case d

    static func ==(_ lhs: Foo, _ rhs: Foo) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case (.a, .a): return true
        case (.b, .b): return true
        case (.c, .c): return true
        case (.d, .d): return true
        default: return false
        }
    }
}
```

You can then do something like this:

```swift
if [Foo.a(x: 0), Foo.b(x: 0), Foo.c].contains(foo) { ... }
```

Another approach would be to add an `index` property, and use that when testing:

```swift
enum Foo {
    case a(x: Int)
    case b(x: Int)
    case c
    case d

    var index: Int {
        switch self {
        case .a: return 0
        case .b: return 1
        case .c: return 2
        case .d: return 3
        }
    }
}
```

And use it along the lines of

```swift
if [Foo.a(x: 0), Foo.b(x: 0), Foo.c].map({ $0.index }).contains(foo.index) { ... }
```

Both solutions are more verbose than the simple switch, and they would be feasible only if you need to use them many times.

Alternatively, you could extend `Array` with something like this:

```swift
extension Array where Element == Foo {
    func matchesCase(_ foo: Foo) -> Bool {
        return contains {
            switch ($0, foo) {
            case (.a, .a): return true
            case (.b, .b): return true
            case (.c, .c): return true
            case (.d, .d): return true
            default: return false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

, and use it like this:

```swift
if [Foo.a(x: 0), Foo.b(x: 0), Foo.c].matchesCase(foo) { ... }
```

And a fourth solution :). Adding a `sameCase` function:

```swift
enum Foo {
    case a(x: Int)
    case b(x: Int)
    case c
    case d

    func sameCase(_ foo: Foo) -> Bool {
        switch self {
        // a little bit more verbose, but don't risk missing new cases
        case .a: if case .a = foo { return true } else { return false }
        case .b: if case .b = foo { return true } else { return false }
        case .c: if case .c = foo { return true } else { return false }
        case .d: if case .d = foo { return true } else { return false }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
if [Foo.a(x: 0), Foo.b(x: 0), Foo.c].contains(where: foo.sameCase) { ... }
// or
if foo.sameCase(.a(x: 0)) || foo.sameCase(.b(x: 0)) || foo.sameCase(.c) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on repeating this test multiple times in multiple places, then duplicating the long winded version over and over would indeed be annoying; however, you can simply encapsulate this bit of code in an extension.

```
extension Foo {
  var isABorC: Bool {
    switch self {
    case .a, .b, .c:
      return true
    default:
      return false
    }
  }
}
```

So now your test becomes something like this:

```
if foo.isABorC { ... }
```

Or you could simply make it part of the enum declaration:

```
enum Foo {
  case a(x: Int)
  case b(x: Int)
  case c
  case d

  var isABorC: Bool {
    switch self {
    case .a, .b, .c:
      return true
    case .d:
      return false
    }
  }
}
```

There is an example is the swift(4.2) documentation using a nested enum to implement ranks for a deck of cards where one might add an `isFaceCard` var.

The bottom line is: you need not endlessly duplicate this bit of text *ad nauseam*.  You can hide it until you identify a more elegant solution.

Answer (score -3):

Unfortunately, there is no other way.

This is because Foo.a is of type (Int) -> Foo. The reason you could not use the array.contains is because a closure and Foo are different types so the compiler assumes you wanted an array of Any.

To see this phenomenon yourself, try out this code:

```swift
print(type(of: Foo.a))
```

You will get `(Int) -> Foo`.

Comment: No.  You don't.  The `switch` statement shown by @Sweeper works fine.

Comment: There is a tiny drop of important information here, which is about the type of `Foo.a` not being `Foo`. But the rest is totally wrong, including implying that `Foo.a` is a closure.

Comment: It is - look at Xcode autocomplete when you type it