# Return Repeating character in swift

Tags: swift, return, return-value

I am trying to find the first repeating character in swift, and returning the character found. I am getting a bunch of errors with this code, I am not sure why this is not working.

```
var myArry = "Hello, World"
var counts = [Character]()

func findRepeating(myArry: String) -> Character
{
    counts = []
    for char in myArry.characters
    {
        if char in counts
        {
            print("Character found")
            return char
        }
        else
        {
            counts.append(char)
        }
    }
    return "A"
}
```

Comment: What is `var counts = {}` supposed to do? Please see the Swift book to learn about arrays and how to initialize them.

Comment: @rmaddy Dictionary to store characters found

Comment: Then read the Swift book to learn about dictionaries.

Comment: @FrankBoccia You need to initialize a dictionary like `[:]` this. Not like `{}`. And also your'e returning nil to the function which is supposed to return `Character`.

Comment: @FrankBoccia: First Google hit for "Swift How to check if an element is in an array": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102024/how-to-check-if-an-element-is-in-an-array.

Answer (score -1):

Most simple answer:

```
let str = "abcdefghijkhlmnop"
var count = 0
for char in str.characters {
    for charNext in str.characters {
        if (char == charNext) {
            count += 1
            if (count > 1) {
                return char           // h
            } 
        }
    }
    count = 0
}
```

Comment: String characters property is deprecated **Xcode 9.1 • Swift 4.1**